# What's the relation of semiotics to cybernetics?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, semiotics

I was looking at the wiki page of [Jakob Johann von Uexküll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Johann_von_Uexk%C3%BCll#Theoretical_biology) where I saw a diagram that resembled a simple feedback model of cybernetics.
What's the relation of semiotics to cybernetics?

Comment: [Cybernetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybernetics) is a transdisciplinary approach for exploring regulatory systems. [Semiotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics) is the study of sign process (semiosis), which is any form of activity, conduct, or any process that involves signs, including the production of meaning. Unlike linguistics, semiotics also studies non-linguistic sign systems. There is common concept: *system*  (and here is where [Jakob Johann von Uexküll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Johann_von_Uexk%C3%BCll) may be pertinent).

Comment: See also D.A. Novikov, [Cybernetics: From Past to Future (Springer, 2016)](https://books.google.it/books?id=LbQvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1), page 1: "Cybernetics is an *interdisciplinary science*. It originated “at the junction” of mathematics, logic, semiotics, physiology, biology and sociology."

Comment: See also [Ludwig von Bertalanffy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_von_Bertalanffy)'s [general system theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_theory#General_systems_research_and_systems_inquiry)